# Sharepoint InputFormSection control look-a-like

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, controls

I'm looking for a similar control to the InputFormSection control in Sharepoint that I want to use in a regular web page that doesn't run in the context of Sharepoint. Here's how the inputformsection looks like : http://graegert.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/01/moss_adminarea_page_structure1.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So do I understand your question correctly? You want to have a control that looks and behave like the InputFormSection control of SharePoint, but it should be able to run outside the context of a SharePoint site?

If so, one approach that you could take is to rip out the generated HTML and use it in your own user control. The IE Developer Toolbar can be of great help to retrieve all other the information (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18359).

Answer (score 0):

It is quite easy to reproduce the control (it is a user control and you have access to the .ascx files). Actually, that's exactly what I ended up doing yesterday.